# Kotlin sort list of list based on parameter in inner list

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I have a list of list that I want to sort based on a date value in inner list. Here's example of my list:

`ClassA(id: String, classb : List<ClassB>)` and ClassB is `ClassB(id: String, date: Date)` so I have list of ClassA which also contain list of ClassB and I want to order/sort List based on descending order of dates in inner classB

Comment: do you want a list of `ClassB` ordered by date with its corresponding `ClassA` or do you want a list of `ClassA` where only the `ClassB` are ordered by date for each `ClassA`... or in other words: what should happen if there are two `ClassB`-dates of any `ClassA`-object that are both before and after other `ClassA`-object-contained `ClassB`-dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following:

```
val int = AtomicInteger(0)
data class A(val bs: List<B>, val id: Int = int.incrementAndGet())
data class B(val date: LocalDate, val id: Int = int.incrementAndGet())
```

and a list (`listOfA`) as follows:

```
A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-24, id=1), B(date=2019-09-25, id=2), B(date=2019-09-23, id=3)], id=4)
A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-21, id=5), B(date=2019-09-22, id=6), B(date=2019-09-23, id=7)], id=8)
A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-19, id=9), B(date=2019-09-23, id=10), B(date=2019-09-29, id=11)], id=12)
```

1. only ordering the class `B` elements (actually I create a new list with completely new `A`-objects... if you do not want that, this can still serve as a starting point):

   ```
   val listOfAWithOrderedB = listOfA.map {
     it.copy(bs = it.bs.sortedByDescending(B::date))
   }
   ```

   which leads to:

   ```
   A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-25, id=2), B(date=2019-09-24, id=1), B(date=2019-09-23, id=3)], id=4)
   A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-23, id=7), B(date=2019-09-22, id=6), B(date=2019-09-21, id=5)], id=8)
   A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-29, id=11), B(date=2019-09-23, id=10), B(date=2019-09-19, id=9)], id=12)
   ```
2. ordering by all `B`-dates and keeping a reference to the actual `A`:

   ```
   val bSortedByDateAndTheirA = listOfA.flatMap { anA ->
     anA.bs.map {
       it to anA
     }
   }
       .sortedByDescending { (b) -> b.date }
   ```

   which leads to a `List<Pair<B, A>>` (again... a possible starting point) as follows:

   ```
   (B(date=2019-09-29, id=11), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-19, id=9), B(date=2019-09-23, id=10), B(date=2019-09-29, id=11)], id=12))
   (B(date=2019-09-25, id=2), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-24, id=1), B(date=2019-09-25, id=2), B(date=2019-09-23, id=3)], id=4))
   (B(date=2019-09-24, id=1), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-24, id=1), B(date=2019-09-25, id=2), B(date=2019-09-23, id=3)], id=4))
   (B(date=2019-09-23, id=3), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-24, id=1), B(date=2019-09-25, id=2), B(date=2019-09-23, id=3)], id=4))
   (B(date=2019-09-23, id=7), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-21, id=5), B(date=2019-09-22, id=6), B(date=2019-09-23, id=7)], id=8))
   (B(date=2019-09-23, id=10), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-19, id=9), B(date=2019-09-23, id=10), B(date=2019-09-29, id=11)], id=12))
   (B(date=2019-09-22, id=6), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-21, id=5), B(date=2019-09-22, id=6), B(date=2019-09-23, id=7)], id=8))
   (B(date=2019-09-21, id=5), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-21, id=5), B(date=2019-09-22, id=6), B(date=2019-09-23, id=7)], id=8))
   (B(date=2019-09-19, id=9), A(bs=[B(date=2019-09-19, id=9), B(date=2019-09-23, id=10), B(date=2019-09-29, id=11)], id=12))
   ```

Comment: if you want to have a mixture of both... sorting list `A` corresponding to its `B`-dates, then you need to tell what should happen if there are several dates within one `A` that could be before/after any other `A'`.

Comment: I will need mixture of both (sorting list A corresponding to its B-dates). My dates are actually DateTime and there's a guarantee that two dates in classB in two classA won't be the same, at least there will be a time difference. Thanks for the above, will try it

Comment: so do you have cases, such as in my example, where `A(id=4)` contains `B`-dates that are actually both, before and after some `B`-dates of `A(id=12)`... how would you want to order that?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I would show the outer entries with higher size first. This that possible? Also I see your solution involves Pairs<A, B> output, how can I get the output in original format i.e instead of List<Pair<A, B>> but List<List<B>>

Comment: hmmm... maybe I wasn't clear enough or I don't understand what you really want... in my second approach I basically have each corresponding `A` in the pair... however each `A` still has its complete list of all possible `B`s... so if you say `List<List<B>>` what do you really expect? if you only need the `B`-dates to be sorted, you can also just do `listOfAs.flatMap { bs }.sortedByDescending { it.date }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Comparator** to use this... here the code sample that you can use

**Comparator object**

```
companion object : Comparator<MyDate> {

override fun compare(a: MyDate, b: MyDate): Int = when {
    a.year != b.year -> a.year - b.year
    a.month != b.month -> a.month - b.month
    else -> a.day - b.day
}}
```

**date model class**

```
data class MyDate (val year: Int, val month: Int, val day: Int) {}
```

**and this is how you can perform sorting**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val myDates = listOfdays
myDates.sortedWith(CompareObjects).forEach { 

    add sorted list
}}
```

Comment: instead of using your own comparator, you may also be interested in [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html)... that way you could also write something like `listOfB.sortedWith(compareBy { it.date })`...